# Processing javascript, objects and firebug

Tags: javascript, json

This is an edit of an earlier post.  for a very novice question.   I have a javascript function that is getting called with a data object. Data appears to be a json string.   However the json string will not parse.  How do I get parse this json string?  Then how do I replace the contents of a div with value from the json string?

## I get the following errors:

`JSON.parse(data)` dies with "unexpected character"
`eval('(' + data + ')');` dies with error  "missing ] after element list".

----  JSON string--------

```
http://jsonlint.com/ calls this a valid json string.
[{"cmd": "as", "id": "#calls", "val": "<h2> Missed Calls</h2><ul></ul>", "prop": "innerHTML"}]
```

---- html ----

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   function missed_calls_callback(data){
      alert("Foo");   // (breakpoint) This alerts 'Foo'
      alert(data.id);  // This prints 'undefined'

      var object1 = JSON.parse(data);
      var object2 = eval('(' + data + ')');  // missing [


      //  How do I do the following?
      //  1.  divname = data.id
      //  2.  content = data.id.val
      //  2.  Replace contents of <div id="divname"> with content
   }
 </script>
 <body>
    And on my page I have div calls.
    I want to fill div calls with
    <div id="divname"> Put stuff here. </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one. I will answer this for the group and the benefit of those who may have this same issue. The issue was invisible carriage returns inside a json string.     `data` contained hidden characters that `JSON.parse` couldn't handle.   I fixed the json string with a combination of methods to eliminate carriage returns that the javascript library couldn't handle.

------server side-------

```
render = render_to_string('templates/file.html', { 'tag': objects })
dajax = Dajax()
dajax.assign('tags','innerHTML', render)
jsonStr =  dajax.json()
jsonStr = ''.join(unicode(jsonStr, 'utf-8').splitlines())
return jsonStr
```

-------client side-----

```
function my_callback(data){
    var dString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var myObject = JSON.parse(dString);
    document.getElementById(myObject[0].id).innerHTML=myObject[0].val;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to "test" with firebug?

```
<body>
    And on my page I have div calls.
    I want to fill div calls with
    <div id="divname"> Put stuff here. </div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     data = {
        cmd:"as", 
        id:"divname", 
        val:"<h2> My Content</h2>"
     };
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById(data.id).innerHTML=data.val;
 </script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfXHW/4/)

Comment: I was just trying to understand firebug some.  it says data.id is undefined.  ??

Comment: Where do you define "data" on your page? In my example you can see it being declared as an object literal.